# Find second highest record from oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data:

```
id  date    mia 

1   1/1/2017    3

1   1/2/2017    1

1   1/3/2017    2

2   1/4/2017    1

2   1/5/2017    4

2   1/6/2017    6

.
.
.
.
```

and so on.

If I give input as `id=1` I should fetch record of `2017-02-01` and if input `id=2` then record of `2017-05-01` i.e record of previous month of the highest date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY mia DESC) AS rn
      FROM table) sub
WHERE rn = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may not define a column named as `date`, instead i use `date_`.
For former versions you may refer to @lad2025 's answer, if you're on oracle12c, you may query with the following :

```
select min(date_) min_date 
  from
(
 select date_
   from mytable
  where id = &i_id
  group by id, date_
  order by date_
  fetch first 2 rows only
 );
```

Comment: The subquery is unnecessary, because `fetch` can be used with `offset`.